# ASP.NET (VB) Loop textbox and assign value to each of them

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, textbox

I have 10 textbox in my web page. I have 10 latest records from my database.

How do I loop through the textboxes and assign the database records into them?

Currently I am using hardcode method:

```
For i = 0 To _datatable.Rows.Count
    If i = 0 Then
        txtbox1.Text = _datatable.Rows(0)("shift").ToString
    ElseIf i = 1 Then
        txtbox2.Text = _datatable.Rows(1)("shift").ToString
    ElseIf i = 2 Then
        txtbox3.Text = _datatable.Rows(2)("shift").ToString
    // and so on...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: so what code have you tried so far?

Comment: @CurseStacker Please look at my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Repeater` control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ID="txtShift" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("shift") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`<%Eval("shift") %>` is what bounds your `TextBox` to the `DataSource`.
Anything you put inside the `<ItemTemplate>` will be repeated for each row in your `DataTable`.

Then on your code behind

```
rptItems.DataSource = _datatable
rptItems.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
</asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind:

```
For i = 1 To dt.rows.count
  Dim _txt As TextBox = pnl1.FindControl("txt" & i.ToString.Trim)
  Dim _row As String = dt.Rows(i)("column name of your datatable").ToString.Trim
  _txt.Text = _row
Next
```

- dt = datatable - records from sql
- hope this code helps.